# "... is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:" - Initialization of a WebServer() object

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

According to the documentation a WebServer is initialized like this in the .cpp class

```
WebServer server(80);
```

To fit this into my created class I would like to do.

```
private:
   WebServer server;
```

in my header and

```
this->server = WebServer(80);
```

in my class definition, so I have a normal declaration of my WebServer.
But this throws the error: ....' **is implicitly deleted because 
the default definition would be ill-formed:**

How can I initialize the WebServer correctly?

**EDIT:**
Ok, so now my code looks like this:

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(String clientId, String clientSecret, String redirectUri);
    private:
        String clientId;
        String clientSecret;
        String redirectUri;
        WebServer server;
};
```

and

```
MyClass::MyClass(String clientId, String clientSecret, String redirectUri):clientId{clientId}, clientSecret{clientSecret}, redirectUri{redirectUri}, server{80}{}
```

Comment: `Foo::Foo() : server{80} {}`

Answer (score 1):

Because of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), the instruction `WebServer server;` tries to **initialize** the variable with an object of type `WebServer` using the default constructor.

To use a different constructor to construct this instance variable, you have to provide it in the constructor's initialization list:

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass()
 :server{80}
{
}
```

This tells the compiler to construct the `server` object with the initialization values `80`, which in turns is given to `WebServer`'s constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I now use a different constructor for the server object. But I still get an error when trying to compile. Has this still to do with my declaration?

Comment: Oh sry, the error is: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with 
_Tp = HTTPUpload; _Dp = std::default_delete<HTTPUpload>]' -     note: declared here: unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

Comment: so that's another question entirely, you're trying to copy a unique_ptr, which is not possible as is copy-constructor is explicitly deleted. Maybe the WebServer has a unique_ptr, and you're doing implicit copies instead of just initializing it ?

Comment: Okay, thank you, I guess I found the problem! Thank you.